# Get full reference in chicago footnote

Tags: chicago-style

I am a complete beginner with Latex so please bare with me...

I am trying to use the chicago package (\usepackage{chicago}
) in order to reference other papers in mine. Does Latex do all the referencing on its own or do I have to be the one writing each footnote manually?

for example:

Is it possible to type something like

```
...it is a temporary condition and can be changed\footnote{\cite{Chua1999}}...
```

and latex will automatically create the correct full reference (for the first time the paper was referenced)? Such as the note form in http://library.sc.edu/pubserv/chicago.pdf

Comment: With `biblatex` you have a `footcite` and a `footfullcite` commands. Moreover there is a `biblatex-chicago` package.

Comment: By all means, if you want Chicago style, please use `biblatex-chicago`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's easy with `biblatex-chicago` package and the `\footfullcite` command, as mentioned in Bernard's comment.

Here is an example

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mybiblio.bib}
@article{Chua1999,
  author = {Chua},
  title = {A title},
  journal = {A Journal},
  year = {1999},
}\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate-trad]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{mybiblio.bib}

\begin{document}

...it is a temporary condition and can be changed\footfullcite{Chua1999}...

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Output (footnote)

[image]

P.S. It has to be compiled with

> pdflatex file
>
> biber file
>
> pdflatex file
>
> pdflatex file

Comment: `biblatex-chicago` recommends using `\autocite` by default; then the program can figure out whether it should be a full citation.

Comment: I tried using your example to see if it works. I copy paste it in the texmaker editor and do a PDFlatex -> BibTex -> PDFlatex -> PDFlatex -> View PDF, but the footnote writes 'Chua1999' instead

Comment: @AlexStyl **Biber**, not **BibTeX**. If you want to use BibTeX, change `backend=biber` to `backend=bibtex`.

Comment: @karlkoeller it does seem to build properly and the cite seems to be okay, but now in the start of the document there is a line saying "music,review,video|eventyearorigyear year urlyear" (no chances to your example done)

Comment: @AlexStyl My bad. `biblatex-chicago` doesn't accept bibtex as backend. You have to run biber instead...

Comment: @AlexStyl See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/27635 to see how to run biber from your editor.

Comment: I set up my texmaker to build with biber and it worked flowlessly. Thank you @karlkoeller!