# What to do here to make biblatex-chicago work properly?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, pdftex

I just tried to run this code in Text Studio but it still dose not work:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mybiblio.bib}
@article{Chua1999,
  author = {Chua},
  title = {A title},
  journal = {A Journal},
  year = {1999},
}\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate-trad]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{mybiblio.bib}

\begin{document}

...it is a temporary condition and can be changed\footfullcite{Chua1999}...

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I read that for biblatex-chicago package, we need to default compiler to: pdflatex+biblatex+pdflatex+pdflatex

I did the same thing as you can see in the screenshot
[image]
But unfortunately, I still do not receive the desired output in the footnote.

I'm just wondering what I need to do to make it work properly.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Did you get an error message? Which one? Please add it to your question!

Comment: Thank you sir! i did not recive any error but I have not received the desired output. The correct output is given in this link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222244/get-full-reference-in-chicago-footnote . but when i run it i only see Chua1999 in footnote (that is the thing i wrote in \footfullcite command and it dose not give me the refrence in footnote) @Mensch

Comment: You need to instruct your editor to run Biber, not BibTeX. Check your editor config against https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. Also "Default Bibliography Tool" as `txs://pdflatex` looks shifty. Surely it should be either BibTeX or Biber.